# How to redirect wordpress homepage to drupal home page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress homepage with the link (exxample:http://online.com/wp) and drupal home page is (exxample:http://online.com/drup). for wordpress homepage alone i need to redirect to drup other than wordpress home page link should be work example: (http://online.com/wp/product-category/product1). i tried to use htaccess but it is not working

redirect 301 /wp/index.php http://online.com/drup

The above one redirect every link in worpdress. please advise me on this

Comment: use href="http://online.com/drup"

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect it via WordPress redirect.

In your theme's functions file, you can write something like this:

```
function homepage_redirect(){
        if( is_front_page() || is_home()  ){
            wp_redirect( 'http://online.com/drup' );
            die;
        }
    }
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'homepage_redirect' );
```

WordPress uses hooks and `template_redirect` is called just before loading appropriate template for the page, we can call the `wp_redirect` function here. Also that die; as last line there is to exit the WP from further execution. Details here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/